# Using play 2 war with play 2.2.1

Tags: java, playframework, war

I am trying to package a (java) play application as war, using this plugin:
https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

It is stated there that play 2.2.X is supported, however the explanation of how to configure seems to assume the existence of a Build.scala file.
From what I understand (I am new to play, have not used any older version) that file is no longer used in play 2.2.1? It does not exist and I have no idea how to integrate it.

Does anybody know how to configure play 2 war in play 2.2.1?
Thanks

EDIT:
Crosspost here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/uLkKW7f4sWI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution can be found in the google groups Link I posted.